# omp flush and cc-NUMA architecture

Tags: multithreading, caching, openmp

there is something that I miss about the cc-NUMA architecture and the need to flush variables. We all know that if two threads modify the same cache line then a "false sharing" condition will rise forcing the cache lines to be reloaded again. 
So why we need to flush variables in order to make thread exchange information?
Suppose that in the serial region you declare :

```
int flag=0;
```

And then in parallel region Thread 0 assigns the shared variable:

```
 flag=1;
```

will Thread 1:

```
while (!flag){}
```

loop ever terminate without a flush ? If not why if we are in a cc-NUMA architecture ?

Comment: Logically speaking, cc-NUMA is no different from any other shared-memory multi-core machine. Its cache-coherence may be a bit (or a lot) slower, but behaviorally it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that the compiler can also perform optimizations that cause the above code to break, not just the CPU.

Therefore, I believe a flush is still necessary regardless of the hardware support for cache coherence.